# .click() does not work with ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Datatable which fetches the data from my server using AJAX.

This code adds the data to the Datatable and also adds some buttons to it

```
                var jsdata = JSON.parse(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < jsdata.length; i++) {
                    var actions =
                            '<div class="btn-group">' +
                                '<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" data-button=\'{"func": "func1"}\' data-process_id="' + jsdata[i][0] + '"><i class="icon-remove"></i> </button>' +
                            '</div>';
                    jsdata[i].push(actions);
                }
```

I also have this code which should grab a click on the created buttons (by the above script)

```
$('button').click(function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Unfortunately the functions does not get called. 
If i place the buttons directly (without the AJAX request) it works fine.

How can i fix this?

Comment: You're looking for event delegation.

Comment: [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Could you just explain me what the differece is? I am very new to Javascript/Jquery. Why does it not work with .click? Thanks

Comment: Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ It attaches event to `document` and delegates event to objects created in the future in `document` scope. Attaching event directly to `button` doesn't work because your buttons are not yet inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach the event handler using `on`

```
$(document).on("click", "button",function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I wanted to point out that you can also use another parent to delegate from, not just document. For example, the first parent DIV that is never dynamically replaced could be used instead of document as a parent from which to delegate the event.